# Why matchstick move apart?

Tags: fluid-statics

When we put two matchstick at some distance in the still water. Why they move apart? When we touched the surface of still water at their center.

Comment: Any images of this effect you could post? I've never seen it occur before.

Comment: I am little confused does surface tension of water compelled the matchstick to move apart or they tends to move in.